# How to terminate (not segue) just one view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am wondering how to make just 1 view terminate in iOS. I am making an app such that in the `viewDidLoad()` it generates **52 random strings** and appends them to an array. I have it so that when you shake the device, it will perform a segue.

The problem with this is that it keeps the items in the array that I mentioned earlier. This means that when it does the user goes into that view again, it will still have the 52 random strings, plus when it goes through the `viewDidLoad` function, it will append 52 more strings, so if the user doesn't terminate the whole entire app, but just segues out of the view and goes back in, there will be 104 strings and not 52.

I don't want the above to happen in my app, so I am wondering how you could just terminate this one view while also performing a segue so that this problem won't happen.

Here is some code from my app:

These are the arrays I had:

```
var theCardsTopPlayerHas = [""]
var theCardsBottomPlayerHas = [""]
var theCardsThatWork = ["2_of_clubs", "2_of_diamonds", "2_of_hearts", "2_of_spades", "3_of_clubs", "3_of_diamonds", "3_of_hearts", "3_of_spades", "4_of_clubs", "4_of_diamonds", "4_of_hearts", "4_of_spades", "5_of_clubs", "5_of_diamonds", "5_of_hearts", "5_of_spades", "6_of_clubs", "6_of_diamonds", "6_of_hearts", "6_of_spades", "7_of_clubs", "7_of_diamonds", "7_of_hearts", "7_of_spades", "8_of_clubs", "8_of_diamonds", "8_of_hearts", "8_of_spades", "9_of_clubs", "9_of_diamonds", "9_of_hearts", "9_of_spades", "10_of_clubs", "10_of_diamonds", "10_of_hearts", "10_of_spades", "jack_of_clubs2", "jack_of_diamonds2", "jack_of_hearts2", "jack_of_spades2", "queen_of_clubs2", "queen_of_diamonds2", "queen_of_hearts2", "queen_of_spades2", "king_of_clubs2", "king_of_diamonds2", "king_of_hearts2", "king_of_spades2","ace_of_clubs", "ace_of_diamonds", "ace_of_hearts", "ace_of_spades"]
```

Here is what the viewDidLoad method has:

```
struct shuffledVar {
    static var shuffled = [String]();
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    upperLabelNumber.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)

    //MARK: - Shuffling Cards

    for _ in 1...52 {

        let shuffledCardList = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(theCardsThatWork.count)))

        let the_card = theCardsThatWork[shuffledCardList]

        print("\(the_card)")

        shuffledVar.shuffled.append(the_card)

        theCardsThatWork.remove(at: shuffledCardList)

        print("Finished Card")

    }

    theCardsTopPlayerHas = Array(shuffledVar.shuffled[0...25])
    theCardsBottomPlayerHas = Array(shuffledVar.shuffled[26...51])

    print("")
    print(shuffledVar.shuffled)

    print("")
    print(theCardsTopPlayerHas)
    print("")
    print(theCardsBottomPlayerHas)

}
```

This is the code that segues the view:

```
    override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "friendToDashboard", sender: self) 

    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using an static variable for the array?

Comment: No I am not using a static variable

Comment: And are you sure the method `viewDidLoad` is called again? Are you sure it is not `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`? Also it would be rally helpful if you could add some code :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I was clear about the viewDidLoad method. What I meant to say is that when the user goes into the view, the viewDidLoad would obviously be triggered. But if the user segues out of the view and goes back in without terminating the app, then the viewDidLoad would be called again. That's what I meant to say. The problem with that is any that happened the first time the user went into the view stays appended in the array even the second time the view. That's why I want to know how to just terminate 1 single view so this doesn't happened. And yes, I will add some of my code.

Comment: Move the string generation and storage into a data model object.  You can create that object once, when the controller is initialized, and not care how many times controller lifecycle methods are called.

Comment: The thing is that if the `ViewDidLoad` method is called, it means that the UIViewController was not in memory (and either should be that array you al talking about). I hope seeing some code will make thing clearer :)

Comment: @PhillipMills if he wants the strings to be random every time the screen is shown it will not work.

Comment: Thank you Nikano, I have just added some code that would probably be very helpful

Comment: @Adam the problem is your `static var shuffled` since it is an static it stays always in memory

Comment: @nikano  That's true, but it's also not part of the problem description.  (i.e. Getting 104 strings when 52 are expected.)

Comment: Thank you so much Nikano, this did indeed work.

Comment: @ Phillip Mills - Nikano's solution solved my problem and I am no longer getting the 104 strings and getting the 52 strings as I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a `static var` to store your array of strings.

To solve this problem there are several solutions depending on what you need. Here there are a couple of solutions:

**Solution 1**

If you really **need** to keep the `shuffled` array as a Singleto, then you can empty the `shuffled` array in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    shuffledVar.shuffled = []

    upperLabelNumber.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)

    ...

}
```

**Solution 2**

If you do **not need** to keep the `shuffled` array as a Singleton, then you can modify it as follows:

```
struct shuffledVar {
    var shuffled = [String]();
}

var shuffled = shuffledVar()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    upperLabelNumber.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)

    //MARK: - Shuffling Cards

    for _ in 1...52 {

        let shuffledCardList = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(theCardsThatWork.count)))

        let the_card = theCardsThatWork[shuffledCardList]

        print("\(the_card)")

        shuffled.shuffled.append(the_card)

        theCardsThatWork.remove(at: shuffledCardList)

        print("Finished Card")

    }

    theCardsTopPlayerHas = Array(shuffled.shuffled[0...25])
    theCardsBottomPlayerHas = Array(shuffled.shuffled[26...51])

    print("")
    print(shuffled.shuffled)

    print("")
    print(theCardsTopPlayerHas)
    print("")
    print(theCardsBottomPlayerHas)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `static var shuffled` so you are using static variable. Do you really need a static variable? If not instead of:

```
struct shuffledVar {
    static var shuffled = [String]();
}
```

use:

```
var shuffled:[String] = []
```

and then in code use:

```
shuffled.append(the_card)
```

But if you need this variable to be static (for example you are using it in some other view controller) just remove all elements before adding a new one:

```
//MARK: - Shuffling Cards
shuffledVar.shuffled.removeAll()
```

You can read more about static vars https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html and more about arrays: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array